# Long stack traces in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

What is the solution for long stack traces in RxJS 5? I.e. stack traces that include asynchronous calls leading to the error being thrown.

I've seen all kinds of hacks for older versions, but nothing for this version except for promises that developers are working on it.

For example, I've encountered the following stack trace:

```
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at Object.subscribeToResult (MyProject\node_modules\src\util\subscribeToResult.ts:82:23)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (MyProject\node_modules\src\operators\mergeMap.ts:138:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (MyProject\node_modules\src\operators\mergeMap.ts:134:10)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (MyProject\node_modules\src\operators\mergeMap.ts:118:12)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (MyProject\node_modules\src\Subscriber.ts:96:12)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (MyProject\node_modules\src\observable\ArrayObservable.ts:124:20)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (MyProject\node_modules\src\Observable.ts:217:19)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (MyProject\node_modules\src\Observable.ts:202:87)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (MyProject\node_modules\src\operators\mergeMap.ts:92:19)
    at Observable.subscribe (MyProject\node_modules\src\Observable.ts:200:16)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (MyProject\node_modules\src\util\subscribeToResult.ts:34:21)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (MyProject\node_modules\src\operators\mergeMap.ts:138:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (MyProject\node_modules\src\operators\mergeMap.ts:134:10)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (MyProject\node_modules\src\operators\mergeMap.ts:118:12)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (MyProject\node_modules\src\Subscriber.ts:96:12)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (MyProject\node_modules\src\observable\ArrayObservable.ts:124:20)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (MyProject\node_modules\src\Observable.ts:217:19)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (MyProject\node_modules\src\Observable.ts:202:87)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (MyProject\node_modules\src\operators\mergeMap.ts:92:19)
    at Observable.subscribe (MyProject\node_modules\src\Observable.ts:200:16)
    at Observable._subscribe (MyProject\node_modules\src\Observable.ts:275:24)
    at Observable.subscribe (MyProject\node_modules\src\Observable.ts:202:63)
```

Now, this is definitely a 100% user error that can be linked to some part of my own code, but it's not really possible to tell where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

Such error appears most likely when you're working with .catch block and request is async with **mergeMap**.

You should return observable from the catch block.

```
 .catch((response) => {
        // Do your things here
        return Rx.Observable.empty();
    });
```

And yes it's not an ideal answer :(

Good luck with debugging!